# How to generate uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1 in a C code using OpenMP?

Tags: c, random, openmp, random-seed

I am trying to write an OpenMP code in which each thread will work on big arrays of uniformly distributed random numbers between 0 and 1. Each thread needs to have different and independent random number distributions. In addition, the random number distributions need to be different every time the code is called. This is what I am using right now. Does this always guarantee each thread has its own/different random number sequences? Will the sequences be different every time the code is called? What is the correct way of doing this? The following code has each thread generating 5 samples but in an actual run it will be order of millions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int numthreads,i;
    #pragma omp parallel private(i)
    {
        int id;
        id=omp_get_thread_num();
        if(id==0) numthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("thread %d \n",id);
        srand(time(0)^omp_get_thread_num());
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            printf("thread %d: %d %.6f \n",id,i,(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "And the random number distributions need to be different every time time the code is called." -->  eventually the distributions will repeat.  How real is this requirement?

Comment: Thanks. Anything that gives similar performance to Matlab's `rand` function will work. This is what I am using a reference.

Comment: `time(0)^omp_get_thread_num()` only provide `UINT_MAX+1` different   distributions.  Likely far less if code invoked many times over the next few days - repeats possible.

Comment: The code will certainly run continuously for many days

Comment: It is not how long the code runs that concerns me.  It is how often the program is called.  If only once, then you are at the mercy of the quality of `rand()`, `RAND_MAX` (maybe only 32767) and `rand()` state size.  Thin ice ahead,  Consider [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60292558/2410359).

Comment: Notice `printf("thread %d: %d %.6f ...` reduces the values presented to 1   in a million (~20 bits) with slightly uneven distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what OS you're using, but if it's Linux or a POSIX compliant system, there's [`erand48()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html) for thread-safe generation of random numbers uniformly distributed in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`. It uses a 48-bit seed that's passed as an argument. Generating the initial seed can be done in a number of ways. OpenBSD and Linux have [`getentropy()`](https://man.openbsd.org/getentropy), BSDs have [`arc4random_buf()`](https://man.openbsd.org/arc4random), you can read from the `/dev/urandom` special file on many OSes, or do something like you're currently using with time, pid, etc. I'd suggest a higher resolution timer than `time()`, though - [`clock_gettime()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) is a good source.

An example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    unsigned short xi[3]; // PRNG state variable

#if 0
    // OpenBSD 5.6+/Linux kernel 3.17+ and glibc 2.25+
    if (getentropy(xi, sizeof xi) < 0) {
      perror("getentropy");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
#else
    // Read from /dev/urandom
    int fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
      perror("open /dev/urandom");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (read(fd, xi, sizeof xi) != sizeof xi) {
      perror("read");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(fd);
#endif

    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
      printf("Thread %d random number %f\n", omp_get_thread_num(), erand48(xi));
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain **how** do you understand the explicit direction, saying *"getentropy() **is not intended for regular code**; please use the arc4random(3) family of functions instead."* - are there any kernel-level side-effects, that have lead to this explicit warning, expressed in the cited man page? Thank you for a beam of light on this.

Comment: @user3666197 Like the manpage says, it's meant to seed a PRNG. You shouldn't be using it to get a lot of random numbers directly (OpenBSD really pushes their arc4random API for that, but it's not portable outside of the BSDs that have adopted it unless you use `libbsd`)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use a random number generator which is designed for parallel use, where you can guarantee that each thread is sampling a different part of the random number sequence. (Providing arbitrary but different seeds to most generators does not guarantee that, since they make no guarantees about how the choice of seed affects where in the sequence you are. Thus you *might* just be offset by one.)

I suggest that you read the [Parallel Random Numbers as Easy as 1,2,3](https://thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf) paper, and then use one of their algorithms, which are implemented in, for instance, Intel MKL (which is available free to everyone).

([MKL supports](https://software.intel.com/en-us/onemkl-developer-reference-c-basic-generators) :-

- Philox4x32-10 counter-based pseudorandom number generator with a
  period of 2**128 PHILOX4X32X10[Salmon11].
- ARS-5 counter-based pseudorandom number generator with a period of 2**128, which uses instructions from the AES-NI set
  ARS5[Salmon11].
  )

By using that you can trivially ensure that each thread's generator will generate an independent sequence so you are not sampling the same series in multiple threads.

Intel MKL can be downloaded from https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl/choose-download

Answer (score 0):

You're using xor of time (integer, in seconds) and thread ID to seed the generator. Clearly not necessarily unique across all threads and all time, so not a good idea. You'd be much better off calling srand with the output of [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) which on most machines (i.e. anything but a tiny embedded CPU) will seed your pseudorandom generator with real entropy.

Sample code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1.0, 2.0);
    for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        // Use dis to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen into a 
        // double in [1, 2). Each call to dis(gen) generates a new random double
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, as the second ticks over, two neighboring threads (say 0 and 1) could easily get the same seed if thread 1 gets time=100 and thread 0 gets time=101.

Comment: And another piece of oblivion — the question asks about C but the answer provides C++.  If you can’t help using C++ when using OpenMP, it won’t matter much.

Comment: True -- if pure C is required, @Shawn's answer is best.